# What is the keyword in .ssh/config for tunneling in the background?

Tags: linux, ssh, unix, openssh

In command line option, we can specify `-N -f` to let it run in the background. How about the identical keywords in `.ssh/config`?

Instead of doing `ssh dest -N -f -L 1337:localhost:1337` I would like to achieve with simple `ssh tunneldest` and it runs in the background.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know (checked `man ssh` and `man ssh_config`) it is not possible to fork to the background using SSH config directives.

Alternatively you could use a bash alias (and put it in your `.bashrc`:

`alias tunnel='ssh dest -N -f -L 1337:localhost:1337'`

Answer (score -1):

Actually I found a way to do this:

```
Host myserver
  Hostname myserver.example.com
  LocalForward 1337 dest:1337
```

So

```
$ ssh -N -f myserver
```

- `-N` for don't execute anything
- `-f` for go to background